# After fill color using floodfill algorithm, opacity of color is increase after drawing by finger on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, flood-fill

I have canvas drawing app. I successfully done integrating floodfill algorithm for filling color for finger drawing circle and rectangle area. My problem is after filling color on finger drawing circle when i used blur mask brush effect and drawing using finger by blur mask brush then whole blur mask brush drawing is repaint again and again. Here is my code:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    private final Paint mDefaultPaint;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    float x, y;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    LinearLayout drawing_layout;
    private Canvas mLayerCanvas = new Canvas();
    private Bitmap mLayerBitmap;
    final Point p1 = new Point();
    private Stack<DrawOp> mDrawOps = new Stack<>();
    private Stack<DrawOp> mUndoOps = new Stack<>();

    boolean isFill = false;
    private SparseArray<DrawOp> mCurrentOps = new SparseArray<>(0);

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);

    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mDefaultPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mDefaultPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mDefaultPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mDefaultPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mDefaultPaint.setStrokeWidth(40);
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        setSaveEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        final int pointerCount = MotionEventCompat.getPointerCount(event);

        switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (isFill == true) {

                int xx = (int) event.getX();
                int yy = (int) event.getY();
                Point pp = new Point(xx, yy);

                /*Point pp = new Point();
                pp.x = (int) event.getX();
                pp.y = (int) event.getY();*/

                final int sourceColor = mLayerBitmap.getPixel(xx, yy);
                final int targetColor = mDefaultPaint.getColor();

                new TheTask(mLayerBitmap, pp, sourceColor, targetColor)
                        .execute();

//              JniBitmap.floodFill(mLayerBitmap, xx, yy, sourceColor,targetColor);

/*              FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
                f.floodFill(mLayerBitmap, pp, sourceColor, targetColor);*/

            }
            for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                final int id = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, p);
                DrawOp current = new DrawOp(mDefaultPaint);
                current.getPath().moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mCurrentOps.put(id, current);
            }
        }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                if (isFill == false) {

                final int id = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, 0);
                DrawOp current = mCurrentOps.get(id);
                final int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
                    x = event.getHistoricalX(h);
                    y = event.getHistoricalY(h);
                    current.getPath().lineTo(x, y);
                }
                x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, 0);
                y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, 0);
                current.getPath().lineTo(x, y);
            }
        }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                final int id = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, p);
                mDrawOps.push(mCurrentOps.get(id));
                mCurrentOps.remove(id);
            }
            updateLayer();
        }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                mCurrentOps.remove(MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, p));
            }
            updateLayer();
        }
            break;

        default:
            return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Bitmap bmp;
        Point pt;
        int replacementColor, targetColor;

        public TheTask(Bitmap bm, Point p, int sc, int tc) {
//          this.bmp = bm;
            mLayerBitmap = bm;
            pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            this.pt = p;
            this.replacementColor = tc;
            this.targetColor = sc;
            pd.setMessage("Filling....");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
//           mLayerBitmap = f.floodFill(bmp, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            f.floodFill(mLayerBitmap, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);

//          New Commented Algorithm
//          f.FloodFill(mLayerBitmap, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            invalidate();
            isFill = false;
        }
    }

    public void fillShapeColor(Bitmap mBitmap2) {
        isFill = true;
    }

    public void setDrawing() {
        isFill = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);
        mLayerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mLayerCanvas.setBitmap(mLayerBitmap);
        updateLayer();
    }

    private void updateLayer() {


        for (DrawOp drawOp : mDrawOps) {
            if (drawOp != null) {
//              drawOp.draw(new Canvas(mLayerBitmap));
                drawOp.draw(mLayerCanvas);
            }
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(mLayerBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < mCurrentOps.size(); i++) {
            DrawOp current = mCurrentOps.valueAt(i);
            if (current != null) {
                current.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    public void operationClear() {
        mDrawOps.clear();
        mUndoOps.clear();
        mCurrentOps.clear();
        // To Clear Whole Canvas
        mLayerCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        updateLayer();
    }

    public void operationUndo() {
        if (mDrawOps.size() > 0) {
            mUndoOps.push(mDrawOps.pop());
            updateLayer();
        }
    }

    public void operationRedo() {
        if (mUndoOps.size() > 0) {
            mDrawOps.push(mUndoOps.pop());
            updateLayer();
        }
    }

    public void setPaintStrokeWidth(float widthPx) {
        mDefaultPaint.setStrokeWidth(widthPx);
    }

    /*public float getPaintStrokeWidth(){
        return mDefaultPaint.getStrokeWidth();

    }*/

    public void setPaintOpacity(int percent) {
        int alphaValue = (int) Math.round(percent * (255.0 / 100.0));
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(combineAlpha(mDefaultPaint.getColor(),
                alphaValue));
    }

    /*public int getPaintOpacity(){
        this.setPaintOpacity(50);
        return mDefaultPaint.getColor();
    }*/

    public void setPaintColor(String color) {
        mDefaultPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(combineAlpha(Color.parseColor(color),
                mDefaultPaint.getAlpha()));
//      mDefaultPaint.setColor(mDefaultPaint.getAlpha());
    }

    public void setPaintColor(int color) {
        mDefaultPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(combineAlpha(color, mDefaultPaint.getAlpha()));
    }

//  New Created
    public void setEraser(int color){
//      mDefaultPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(color);
        mDefaultPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    public void setPaintMaskFilter(MaskFilter filter) {
        mDefaultPaint.setMaskFilter(filter);
    }

    /*public MaskFilter getPaintMaskFilter(){
        return mDefaultPaint.getMaskFilter();

    }*/

    public void setPaintShader(BitmapShader shader) {
        mDefaultPaint.setShader(shader);
    }

    public void setPaintColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        mDefaultPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    private static int combineAlpha(int color, int alpha) {
        return (color & 0x00FFFFFF) | ((alpha & 0xFF) << 24);
    }

    private static class DrawOp {
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private final Path mPath = new Path();

        public DrawOp(Paint paint) {
            reset(paint);
        }

        void reset(Paint paint) {
            mPath.reset();
            update(paint);
        }

        void update(Paint paint) {
            mPaint.set(paint);
        }

        void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        public Path getPath() {
            return mPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some screenshots for the question

Comment: ok wait i will upload screenshot

Comment: please check once again i share screenshot here

Comment: problem is on updateLayer() which is one line of code for clearing the canvas color. But is very important. Without that code i cant get undo and redo opration for drawing

Comment: are you shown screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is layers count constant in each draw call? Maybe you set wrong Paint opacity?

Comment: i am stuck around one week in this problem if you have syntax then please guide me for this. i used lots of things and code for that. but not success

Comment: when i remove mLayerCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); line from updateLayer() then works fine but not work undo and redo.

Comment: and when i set mLayerCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); line in updateLayer() then floodfill not work perfect. Filled Color is gone after line drawn.

Comment: That's not a chat) If I find a solution, I've post the answer)

Comment: @anil: please stop finding solution for this question. i find my own way, I need not your help.

Comment: and also u r not eligible for answering this questions.

Comment: @jack what was the solution ???

Comment: hi @HarinKaklotar... pls tell me exact what happen in your code?

Comment: @jack i had same problem as you, but now i have solved it :)

Comment: is possible to save the drawing path as JSON ?@jack

Comment: is possible to save the drawing path as JSON ?@jack

Comment: I think you need to convert Point object Value as json and store as json using gson Android library. I am not sure about it but I think it's possible.